# HDMI sound is not working on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, 21.04

I tried every search result that I could find, including some on Ask Ubuntu, but I am unable to get sound working. I have a new installation of 21.04 on a ASUS TUF B500 motherboard and RX5500 GPU. There is no HDMI audio on the connected TV. The HDMI-6 device has the connection to the TV.

I can see the active volume meter in pauvcontrol, but no sound from the speakers.

I've tried restarting ALSA/pulseaudio, sending audio direct to the device via ALSA. Sending directly from aplay or speaker-test is not working.

I really don't want to go back to remove pulse and set up ALSA on it's own, writing asound files, etc.

Results of `lspci` :

```
09:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
0b:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

Results of `dmesg | grep -i sound` :

```
[    4.647026] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.647162] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.647163] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode
[    4.647307] snd_hda_intel 0000:0b:00.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.403503] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: ALCS1200A: SKU not ready 0x00000000
[    5.403976] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALCS1200A: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    5.403982] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.403986] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.403990] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.403992] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[    5.403994] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    5.403996] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    5.403999] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    5.404001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
[    5.641340] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.1: bound 0000:09:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[ 1511.572448] snd_hda_intel 0000:09:00.1: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
```

System ALSA info at
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0abb674e0e8ce6d10758ffd298bcf0e9f5d88111

Comment: "*There is no HDMI audio on the connected TV. The HDMI-6 device has the connection to the TV.*" - This part of your question is very ambiguous and may be important. Can you clarify exactly how everything is physically connected?

Comment: The TV is producing no audio from its speakers. The TV is connected via an HDMI cable to the HDMI 6 of pauvcontrol (5 if starting at 0) port of the GPU audio device. Listed as connected by ALSA on  Card 0 Device 11.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this particular TV was sending a bad EDID so that it wasn't functioning as a sound sink. Multiple other devices worked when connected. If I was going to need to use this TV I could edit the EDID and load it on startup.